# required = True not taking effect in Django form field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

what i want is to make the DateField and CharField required so that the form cant be submitted with the fields empty, but even after setting required = True in both it doesn't take effect and end up throwing an error on saving the form, i dnont know where am getting it wrong

here is the form class:

```
class RepairOrderForm(forms.ModelForm):

    brand = forms.CharField(
        required=True,
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                "placeholder": " e.g DELL",
            }
        )

    )

    model = forms.CharField(
        required=True,
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                "placeholder": "Device model",
            }
        )
    )

    serial_no_or_IMEI = forms.CharField(
        required=True,
        label="Serial No/IMEI",
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                "placeholder": "Device serial No/EMEI",
            }
        )
    )

    fault_details = forms.CharField(
        required=True,
        widget=forms.Textarea(
            attrs={
                "placeholder": " A detailed description of the fault",
            }
        )
    )

    pick_up_date = forms.DateField(
        required=True,
        # initial = datetime.date.today,
        widget=forms.DateTimeInput(

            attrs={
                # "class": "datepicker",
            }
        )
    )

    coupon_code = forms.CharField(
        required=False,
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                "placeholder": "Got a coupon/voucher use it here and get a discount on your repair order",
            }
        )
    )

    survey = forms.CharField(
        required=False,
        widget=forms.Textarea(
            attrs={
                "placeholder": "How did you hear about us",
            }
        )
    )

    terms_and_condition = forms.BooleanField(
        required=True,
        label=' I have read and agree to the'
    )

    class Meta:
        model = RepairOrderModel
        fields = [
            'device_type',
            'brand',
            'model',
            'serial_no_or_IMEI',
            'fault_details',
            'pick_up_date',
            'coupon_code',
            'survey',
            'terms_and_condition'
        ]
```

and here is the model:

```
class RepairOrderModel(models.Model):
    device_type_choices = [
        ('LAPTOP', 'LAPTOP'),
        ('PHONE', 'PHONE'),
        ('DESKTOP', 'DESKTOP'),
        ('WRISTWATCH', 'WRISTWATCH'),
        ('DRONE', 'DRONE'),
        ('LED/LCD TV', 'LED/LCD TV'),
        ('OTHERS', 'OTHERS'),
    ]
    
    order_tracking_choices = [
        ('PENDING', 'PENDING'),
        ('PICKED UP', 'PICKED UP'),
        ('REPAIR IN PROGRESS', 'REPAIR IN PROGRESS'),
        ('REPAIR DONE', 'REPAIR DONE'),
        ('READY FOR DELIVERY', 'READY FOR DELIVERY'),
        ('DELIVERED','DELIVERED')
    ]
    
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    order_id = models.CharField(max_length=120, default="")
    device_type = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices = device_type_choices, default = 'LAPTOP')
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=120, default="")
    model = models.CharField(max_length=120, default="")
    serial_no_or_IMEI = models.CharField(max_length=120, default="")
    fault_details = models.TextField()
    pick_up_date = models.DateField()
    order_tracking = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices = order_tracking_choices, default = 'PENDING')
    coupon_code = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="")
    survey = models.TextField()
    terms_and_condition = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    order_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.owner.username} Repair Order'
```

and here is the view:

```
@login_required
def RepairOrderView(request):
    page_tittle = "Repair Order"

    if request.method == 'POST':
        p_u_form = ProfileUpdateForm(
            request.POST, instance=request.user.profile)
        repair_order_form = RepairOrderForm(request.POST)
        repair_order_form.instance.owner = request.user
        if repair_order_form and p_u_form.is_valid():
            p_u_form.save()
            repair_order_form.save()
            username = request.user
            messages.success(
                request,
                f'{username}, Thanks for placing a repair order . Our customer care will be contacting you soon, to confirm and process your request'
            )
            odr_id = RepairOrderModel.objects.all().filter(
                owner=request.user).order_by('-order_date')[0].order_id

            content = f"Thanks for Placing a repair order. Your Order ID is {odr_id} . Our customer care will be contacting you soon, to confirm and process your request"
            html_msg = render_to_string('repairsquad_home_app/email_templates/email.html', context={
                'username': request.user.username,
                'content': content,
            })
            send_mail(
                "REPAIR SQUAD NOTIFICATION",
                f"Hi {request.user.username} Thanks for Placing a repair order. Your Order ID is {odr_id} . Our customer care will be contacting you soon, to confirm and process your request ",
                settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
                [request.user.email],
                fail_silently=True,
                html_message=html_msg,
            )

            admin_content = f"THE USERNAME ABOVE PLACE A REPAIR ORDER WITH ORDER ID {odr_id} . PLEASE CHECK IT UP AND PROCESS"
            admin_html_msg = render_to_string('repairsquad_home_app/email_templates/email.html', context={
                'username': request.user.username,
                'content': admin_content,
            })
            send_mail(
                "REPAIR SQUAD NOTIFICATION",
                f"THE USERNAME ABOVE PLACE A REPAIR ORDER WITH ORDER ID {odr_id} . PLEASE CHECK IT UP AND PROCESS",
                settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
                [settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER],
                fail_silently=True,
                html_message=admin_html_msg,
            )
            return redirect('profile')
        else:
            messages.error(
                request,
                f'{username}, Please fill the pickup date'
            )
            return redirect('profile')

    else:
        repair_order_form = RepairOrderForm()
        p_u_form = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user.profile)

    context = {
        'page_tittle': page_tittle,
        'repair_order_form': repair_order_form,
        'p_u_form': p_u_form
    }
    return render(request, 'repairsquad_home_app/repair_order_form.html', context)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `.is_valid()` on the `repair_order_form` as well. By writing `if repair_order_form and p_u_form.is_valid():` you check the *truthiness* of the `RepairOrderForm`. Since the `RepairOrderForm` does not override `__bool__`, it means that it will always be `True`.

You thus write the view as:

```
    if request.method == 'POST':
        p_u_form = ProfileUpdateForm(
            request.POST, instance=request.user.profile)
        repair_order_form = RepairOrderForm(request.POST)
        repair_order_form.instance.owner = request.user
        if repair_order_form.is_valid() and p_u_form.is_valid():
            # …
```

Comment: ok it validates now but what i really want is that the empty field in the form should prompt the user even before the post request is initiated, it works for other field but not working for the fault_details and pick_up_date field

Comment: @JephtahJephtah: that should be done with some JavaScript that checks if the `required` attribute is set in an input field.

Comment: ok i thought Django have it built into its template engine because it worked for other fields even without any JavaScript or is it coming from the CSS fromwork (materializcss) am using?

Answer (score 0):

3 years later...

Just for clearing out any misunderstandings: Django can handle that, as Jephtah suspected, just use a datalist like this:

```
<label for="scoreNo">Score 1-5</label>
<input id="Score" name="Score" type="tel" list="defaultValues" />

<datalist id="defaultValues">
<option value="1"></option>
<option value="2"></option>
<option value="3"></option>
<option value="4"></option>
<option value="5"></option>
</datalist>
```